# Set response headers not using filter - RESTeasy

Tags: java, http, http-headers, httpresponse, resteasy

I am trying to set a header value in a response from a RESTful endpoint using RESTeasy. I know that I can read header parameters using @HeaderParam but I want to change the value of that header parameter for the response. How can I do this without using a filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RESTEasy can inject `HttpResponse` which enables you to set header parameters.

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {
    @Context org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpResponse response;

    @GET @Path("/") public void setHeader(){
        response.getOutputHeaders().putSingle("X-Some-Header", "value");
    }
}
```